# run another program with credentials

Tags: powershell

what I'm trying to do is add a user to the local admin group then launch a program with those credentials. I have the first part working:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME   
$srvgroup = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$env:COMPUTERNAME+"/Administrators, Group")   
$srvgroup.name  
$srvgroup.add("WinNT://userID,user")
$srvgroup.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
```

The second part is what I can't seem to get working correctly.

```
Start-Process runas.exe -Credential DOMAIN\user -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Misc\SecureClient" -verb runas}'
```

I don't get an error message but the program does not start. I should get a popup window for the application but nothing happens when I try it this way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like, don't really like it but it works:

```
start-process "cmd.exe" "/c D:\Scripts\client_connect.cmd"
```

that .cmd file is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\username"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\sclient.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

`DOMAIN\user` is not a full credential.  You need to do something like this:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "opensesame" -Force -AsPlainText
$cred = new-object pscredential 'Domain\user',$passwd
Start-Process -Credential $cred ...
```

Comment: that didn't work. Actually it wouldn't put in the domain\user in the popup and wouldn't launch the program.

Comment: I can get it to work in a .cmd like this:
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\password"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\sclient.cmd"

but not in powershell

Comment: the above one is incorrect...
I can get it to work in a .cmd like this: C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\username"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx\sclient.cmd" but not in powershell